# jQuery assign colors to li list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 items in  and I want to assign 4 different background-color to each of the links, but I don't want the colors to randomize.. lets say if I have this structure

```
<div id="div_id">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">More Info</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

how would that be possible?

I have the list of colors. they are (green, blue, red, black)

I tried

```
$("#div_id ul li").each(function() {
 $(this).css("background","green");
});
```

To be honest I don't know how would I apply those colors. I can store them in an array but how would I loop and assign the colors?

Comment: If you don't provide any code, people assume you haven't tried anything. If you haven't tried anything, we assume you don't know javascript. If you don't know javascript, you shouldn't be using jQuery. Also, if you don't want the colors to be random, what DO you want them to be?

Comment: You are giving so very few requirements that I don't see why `style='background-color: #XXXXXX;'` doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    var color=['red','green','blue','yellow'];
    $('#div_id ul li').each(function(i){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor',color[i]);
    });
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NjqYA/).

As you asked for a hover effect on each item by applying a light color on hover I've gave you two examples **1.** http://jsfiddle.net/NjqYA/2/ **2.** http://jsfiddle.net/NjqYA/4/

Comment: This worked for me, now how would I make a hover on it? Like on hover the first element changes its color to light red, second to light green and so on?

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't want to assign a class or ID to each of the individual `<li>` then you could use the nth child selector like so:

```
$("#div_id li:nth-child(1)").css({"background-color":"red"});
$("#div_id li:nth-child(2)").css({"background-color":"green"});
$("#div_id li:nth-child(3)").css({"background-color":"blue"});
$("#div_id li:nth-child(4)").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
```

Answer (score 1):

like this ?  http://jsbin.com/oxaqub/5/edit#preview

[image]